# Showing errors when running groovy script in maven vs. running it in IDE

Tags: java, maven, groovy, ide, gmaven-plugin

It is a maven project. To build and run groovy script "gmavenplus" plugin is used. When I run script in maven, even when I apply the -X option, the error looks like:

```
mvn -X clean install gplus:execute
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on
>   project users_rest_updater: Error occurred while calling a method on a
>   Groovy class from classpath. InvocationTargetException: No such
>   property: args for class: Script1 -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.5:execute
>   (default-cli) on project users_rest_updater: Error occurred while
>   calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error
>   occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.     at
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.ExecuteMojo.doExecute(ExecuteMojo.java:128)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.ExecuteMojo.execute(ExecuteMojo.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:118)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.ExecuteMojo.executeScripts(ExecuteMojo.java:195)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.ExecuteMojo.doExecute(ExecuteMojo.java:124)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such
>   property: args for class: Script1     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
>     at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:4)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)

I run the same script from IDE (Intellij IDEA), but in the console it writes exact error, in my case it is:

> ```
> Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
>   at MainApp.run(MainApp.groovy:3)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
>   ... 1 more
> ```

current pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scripts>
                        <script>file:///${project.basedir}/src/main/groovy/MainApp.groovy</script>
                    </scripts>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.6</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

How can I force maven to show exact error? Without it I cannot see a way to find what's going wrong. For java code, maven always works fine. You always can see the main cause of the problem. 
Probably it is a problem of `gmavenplus` maven plugin, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you running with `-X` isn't that `No such property: args for class: Script1` not enough? And `Script1.groovy:4`...can you show your pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I've attached my pom.xml file. Not the problem has been resolved by adding dependency to commons-cli, but the main problem for me, why I could not the error when run it via maven, at the same time, my IDE displays the reason why it fails

Answer (score 2):

If you just run the script as a Groovy script in IntelliJ, it won't know about any of your project dependencies.  GMavenPlus includes your Maven dependencies in the classpath it uses to execute your scripts.  To run as a standalone script, you'll have to add the dependencies needed with [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html).  Note that using Grape inside scripts executed by GMavenPlus also works.

If you're trying to read arguments passed from commandline, the arguments will be consumed by Maven, GMavenPlus won't have an opportunity to read them.  If you need the script to be invokable both as standalone and through Maven, you should set [properties](http://groovy.github.io/GMavenPlus/execute-mojo.html#properties) for Maven usage, and check in your script if they're set before parsing args.

If `args` is giving you trouble, you could try `this.args`, they're equivalent.